# iOS Calendar Events View representation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, nscalendar

What would be the best approach to implement the Calendar Events as shown below [iOS 8.3]:

[image: Events]

The underlying view is a `UITableView` for sure. But how can I **overlap** different views as we have it here? Also is it possible for a view to **overlap** between different `UITableViewCell`?

And the touch events on these event views are flawless.

Any suggestions/lead are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a table view, it's his father a collection view.
Collection views are more abstracted and require more implementations, using a custom flow layout you can do amazing things.
More info in the official Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) and for that kind of calendar view there is an awesome article on [objectivec.io](http://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/)

Comment: No problem, you can achieve something similar also using Table Views, but collection views are much more flexible for complicated layout.